# Porque Quando realizo Check in no TFS minhas DLL não sobem?

Tags: team-foundation-server

Estou com um problema ainda não domino Team Foundation porém quando algum funcionário tenta baixar o projeto não vem as DLL no caso toda vez tem que ficar adicionando no projeto manualmente e realizando compilações por camada para que a mesma seja identificada, como resolvo isso é possível criar uma pasta de compartilhamento dessas Dll para que todos possam utilizar??

Comment: De uma olhada neste link, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/63904b5e-2dab-4489-9364-583a43bc7eac/keep-referenced-dll-in-tfs?forum=tfsversioncontrol

Answer (score 1):

Se você está fazendo o check-in através do Visual Studio ou do Explorer (tem que ter instalado o Power Tools), as dll´s

não serão incluídas automaticamente

- Versionar dll´s no controle de versão é uma boa prática, bibliotecas/frameworks atualmente são melhores distribuídos

via Nuget, existe um repositório público no qual você pode distribuir os pacotes ou se é um framework interno de uma

empresa você pode instalar uma versão interna do Nuget

- As dll´s dos projetos de uma solution quando compiladas e ficam na pasta bin nunca devem ser colocadas no controle de

versão, toda vez que o desenvolvedor apertar F5 ele deverá fazer check-out do arquivo o que é extremamente incomodo e você não ganha nada em versioná-las. Os binários para distribuição devem ser gerados em um máquina, build machine, com o TFS você pode usar o Team Build e eles serão disponibilizados em uma pasta Drop, mas não através do TFS.
Todos os controladores de versão ficam inchados quando arquivos binários são colocados neles desnecessariamente.

Comment: +1 por mencionar a possibilidade de instalar um nuget privado.